# how to predict multiple dependent columns from 1 independent column

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

is it possible to predict multiple dependent columns from independent columns?

**Problem Statement:** I have to predict 5 factors(cEXT, cNEU,cAGR, cCON, cOPN) on the basis of STATUS column, so input variable will be STATUS column only and target variables are (cEXT, cNEU,cAGR, cCON, cOPN).

[image]

here in the above data STATUS is an independent column and cEXT, cNEU,cAGR, cCON, cOPN are the dependent columns, how can I predict those?

```
# independent and dependent variable split
X = df[['STATUS']]
y = df[["cEXT","cNEU","cAGR","cCON","cOPN"]]
```

right now I am predicting only one column so repeating the same thing 5 times so I am creating 5 models for 5 target variables.

**Code:**

```
X = df[['STATUS']]
y = df[["cEXT","cNEU","cAGR","cCON","cOPN"]]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=5)


from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer

ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('step1', TfidfVectorizer(), 'STATUS')
],remainder='drop')

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, recall_score, classification_report, cohen_kappa_score
from sklearn import metrics 
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# ########## 
# RandomForest
# ##########
model = Pipeline([
        ('column_transformers', ct),
        ('model', RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'gini', n_estimators=100, n_jobs = -1, class_weight = 'balanced', max_features = 'auto')),
    ])

# creating 5 models, can I create 1 model?
model_cEXT = model.fit(X_train, y_train['cEXT'])
model_cNEU = model.fit(X_train, y_train['cNEU'])
model_cAGR = model.fit(X_train, y_train['cAGR'])
model_cCON = model.fit(X_train, y_train['cCON'])
model_cOPN = model.fit(X_train, y_train['cOPN'])
```

Comment: Do you have the code you’re using to predict the first variable ?

Comment: @anarchy, yes i have let me update it

Comment: @anarchy, can you show me some code in deeplearning? because I have created 5 models in deep learning too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multioutput classifier from scikit-learn.

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
```

```
clf = MultiOutputClassifier(RandomForestClassifier()).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.predict(X_test)
```

Reference:
[Official document of MultiOutputClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html#sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library `scikit-multilearn` which is very good for these tasks. There are several ways to do multi-label classification such as `PowerSet`, `ClassifierChain` etc. These are very well covered in this library.

Below is a sample of how it will replace your current code.

```
X = df[['STATUS']]
y = df[["cEXT","cNEU","cAGR","cCON","cOPN"]]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=5)

# Rest of your code
==========================
# The new code

from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix



classifier = BinaryRelevance(
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(criterion = 'gini', n_estimators=100, n_jobs = -1, class_weight = 'balanced', max_features = 'auto'),
    require_dense = [False, True]
)

model = Pipeline([
        ('column_transformers', ct),
        ('classifier', classifier),
    ])

model.fit(X_train, y_train.values)
res = model.predict(X_test)
res = csr_matrix(res)
res.todense()
```

You can explore other methods [here](http://scikit.ml/modelselection.html).

In TensorFlow you can do this using `sigmoid` activation and `binaryCE` loss on all the units. As below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization

tfidf_calculator = TextVectorization(
                  standardize = 'lower_and_strip_punctuation',
                  split       = 'whitespace',
                  max_tokens  = 100,
                  output_mode ='tf-idf',
                  pad_to_max_tokens=False)

tfidf_calculator.adapt(df['Status'].values)

tfids = tfidf_calculator(df['Status'])

X = tfids.numpy()
y = df[["cEXT","cNEU","cAGR","cCON","cOPN"]].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=5)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(100,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32)
```

The thing to take note of in TensorFlow is that you need a dense matrix as input. There might be a way to use sparse but I didn't find any.